# Linker error while building firebase ios sdk binding for xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, firebase

I have created ios binding in xamarin for the latest firebase sdk. I added following

```
[assembly: LinkWith("Firebase.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "CFNetwork Security SystemConfiguration", LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -fobjc-arc -licucore -lc++")]
```

When i compile, during the 'Compiling to native code' stage, the compiler errors out with following message:

```
error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FirebaseHandle. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FirebaseHandle' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

[Update]

On further analysis, i found one of the header file of firebase sdk has following entry

```
typedef NSUInteger FirebaseHandle;
```

I have added corresponding binding information in ApiDefinition.cs file as well

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface FirebaseHandle
{
}
```

But i still get the error

Comment: This lib by any change? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343786/linker-errors-when-adding-firebase-framework-to-ios-project

Comment: Yes, but thats a very old post. I am using the latest version of the sdk as it is

Comment: But did you add that library "libc++.dylib"?

Comment: I did - LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -fobjc-arc -licucore -lc++"

Comment: One more update, this works in simulator but fails to deploy on a device - iphone 5s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

`SmartLink = true`

To the `x.linkwith.cs` file

and **remove** from your `ApiDefinition.cs`

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface FirebaseHandle
{
}
```